# Castle ActiveRecord - SessionScopeWebModule

Tags: c#, castle-activerecord

Now and again im getting the following error
"Seems that the framework isn't configured properly. (isWeb != true and SessionScopeWebModule is in use) Check the documentation for further information"

and my web app crashes

my web.config is so..

```
<activerecord isweb="true">
    <config>
      <add key="connection.driver_class" value="NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver" />
      <add key="dialect" value="NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect" />
      <add key="connection.provider" value="NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider" />
      <add key="connection.connection_string_name" value="main" />
      <add key="proxyfactory.factory_class" value="NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle"/>

    </config>
  </activerecord>
```

any ideas, on what I need to change\add?
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

isWeb is case sensitive.

```
<activerecord isWeb="true">
```

From the source:

```
XmlAttribute isWebAtt = section.Attributes["isWeb"];
```

They aren't being nice about case :)